# how to pass a ("/") through href

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am passing an id containing `/` eg: `171/CR/EOW1/14` in the link.

It is showing correctly, but in the controller function it is taking only the first letters before the slash. eg: `171`

How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your question is incredibly vague.  But for the purposes of this, I'll assume that you want to pass the whole string `171/CR/EOW1/14`.  Not parts of the string as different params.

you are using an un-escaped slash.  So codeigniters' routing thinks the parts of the url after the 171 are more parameters in the route string.

if you want to pass a url, use `urlencode()` and then `urldecode()` to handle the slashes in the string you want to pass.

Or use `addslashes()`.

[addslahes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

[urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uri_segment`, which should help.

```
http://example.com/index.php/controller/action/1stsegment/2ndsegment
```

it will return

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // controller
$this->uri->segment(2); // action
$this->uri->segment(3); // 1stsegment
$this->uri->segment(4); // 2ndsegment
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.6 you can retrieve as a variable argument list which can be specified with the `...` (spread) operator

```
function do_something($first, ...$all_the_others)
{
    var_dump($first);
    var_dump($all_the_others);
}
```

or if you are using a lesser version you have to specify separate arguments variables

```
function do_something($first, $second, $third)
{
    var_dump($first);
    var_dump($second);
    var_dump($third);
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can route the url to this function like

```
$route['products/(:any)'] = 'catalog/do_something';
```

Please check the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) for more details about url routing

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. They're asking how to parse a certain part of that URL in a router, not how to declare variadic functions.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca No. You have to route your url to this function like `$route['product/(:any)'] = 'controller/do_something';` I'll update the answer.

Comment: Then please add a relevant example, because as it is your answer looks just like an explanation of variadic functions without any context.

Answer (score 0):

**Passing URI Segments to your methods in codeigniter** [visit codeIgniter docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods)

If your URI contains more than two segments they will be passed to your method as parameters.

For example, let’s say you have a URI like this:

```
example.com/index.php/products/shoes/sandals/123
```

Your method will be passed URI segments 3 and 4 (“sandals” and “123”):

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller {

        public function shoes($sandals, $id)
        {
                echo $sandals;
                echo $id;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can you use a question mark like:

```
?first=171&second=CR
```

For more information, see e.g. http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: Although this link might contain the answer, it is better just to post the answer directly here.